# Show 3 more items using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create this design but I'm not sure how I can hide some items in the array.

Where can I insert the `SHOW 3 MORE` in between the objects in the array? and toggle the items that been hide.
Hope someone can help me. I'm using ReactJS

[image]

Here's what I created so far creating the codes below

[image]

Here's my code so far

```
const payments = [
  {
    year: 2022,
    timeline: [
    {
      key: 0,
      title: "due on Jun 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      desc: "Make sure you have enough balance on your GCash wallet.",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Due",
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      title: "Paid on Jun 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      title: "Paid on May 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      title: "Paid on April 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      title: "Paid on March 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      title: "Unpaid last Feb 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Unpaid",
    },
    {
      key: 6,
      title: "Paid on Jan 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
  ],
},
{
  year: 2021,
  timeline: [
    {
      key: 0,
      title: "Paid on Dec 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 1,
      title: "Paid on Nov 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 2,
      title: "Paid on Oct 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 3,
      title: "Paid on Sep 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 4,
      title: "Paid on Aug 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 5,
      title: "Paid on Jul 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 6,
      title: "Paid on Jun 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 7,
      title: "Paid on May 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 8,
      title: "Paid on April 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 9,
      title: "Paid on March 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
    {
      key: 10,
      title: "Unpaid last Feb 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Unpaid",
    },
    {
      key: 11,
      title: "Paid on Jan 1, 2022",
      subtitle: "Premium Payment (Scheduled)",
      amount: "Php 1,100",
      status: "Paid",
    },
  ],
},
];
```

Then mapping it

```
<Timeline className="payment-tracker">
   {payments.map(item => (
      <TimelineItem>
        <TimelineSeparator className={`payment__separator--${item.status}`}>
          <TimelineDot className="payment__dot" id={item.status !== "" ? `paymentStatus--${item.status}` : `paymentStatus--Default`}>
            {getIcon(item.status)}
          </TimelineDot>
          <TimelineConnector className="payment__connector" id={item.status !== "" ? `paymentStatus--${item.status}` : `paymentStatus--Default`} />
        </TimelineSeparator>
        <TimelineContent className="payment__content" id={item.status !== "" ? `paymentStatus--${item.status}` : `paymentStatus--Default`}>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid xs={8}>
              <p className="payment__content--title">{item.title}</p>
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={4}>
              <p className="payment__content--amount">{item.amount}</p>
            </Grid>
            <Grid xs={12}>
              <p className="payment__content--subtitle">{item.subtitle}</p>
              <p className="payment__content--desc">{item.desc}</p>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </TimelineContent>
      </TimelineItem>
    ))}
  </Timeline>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a state `const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false)`
2. Slice the array `payments.slice(0, isShown ? payments.length : 2).map(item => ( // ...`
3. Add **show more** button `<button onClick={() => setIsShown(true)}>Show more</button>`